# Jquery magicline with arrow

Tags: jquery, css

I trying to change a menu with bottom borders to have a bottom arrow.

e.g.: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBES4.png

https://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/¨

```
#magic-line { 
    position: absolute;
     bottom: -2px; 
     left: 0; 
     width: 100px; 
     height: 2px; 
    background: #fe4902;
}
```

Tried the following but it does not work.

```
#magic-line {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

#magic-line:after, #magic-line:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#magic-line:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#magic-line:before {
    border-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #999;
    border-width: 11px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0shrxyee/

Comment: We're going to need to see some more code than that. Could you add your JS or better yet put it on plunker/jsbin/codepen (whichever service you prefer)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0shrxyee/

Comment: Thanks. Though this seems to work. What do you mean by bottom arrow?

Comment: Look here: http://i.imgur.com/3onjcjV.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an arrow like the one you are looking for, you can add the following to your css file:

```
#magic-line { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 2px; 
    background: #fe4902;
  overflow:visible !important;
}
#magic-line:after, #magic-line:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#magic-line:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
#magic-line:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

Essentially what this does is it adds an "element" before and after the magic line, and gives them borders which create the appearance of an arrow on your item.

You can create an arrow tailored to you here: http://www.cssarrowplease.com/

Try to understand the CSS on how this works and you can make the arrow look exactly the way you want it to.

If the arrow does not appear during animation, this seems to happen in browsers which use hardware acceleration for css animations with pseudo-elements. The fix is to add `overflow: visible !important` to the element containing the pseudo-elements.

i.e.:

```
#magic-line { 
  overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Comment: But how could I do so the arrow also slides?

Comment: That's an odd bug, but the solution is to add this line inside the #magic-line css: overflow:visible !important;

Comment: Updating answer. Try that instead.